# What algorithm can I use to spread a workload between two processor with fixed resources?

Tags: algorithms, math, sorting, distribution

I need to write an algorithm to allocate x number of tasks to 2 processors per day.

I know the following:

1. Exact amount of time it will take to complete each task
2. The exact amount of time available for each processor for the day

I need to try and use the exact number of resources every day, or have as little extra processing time as possible on top of each processor.

What algorithm could I use to sort these tasks to each processor?

For example, in this example problem:

[image: Task allocation problem]

I know the total time allocated adds to 1302 and there are 10 boxes on each plot so a box represents 130.2~. I've tried manually sorting them into the two processors. I've also tried using an algorithm to fit large numbers first, then smaller numbers, but this isn't very resource efficient

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: added an example

Comment: This looks like a variation of the 0-1 knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem